# This iPhone 6 is running iOS 11.3.1 (15E302), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode 9.2 with Sierra 10.3.3 . And my iPhone 6 is with 11.3.1 (15E302). I'm unable to use my iPhone 6 for the test purpose of my IOS apps. Because, the Xcode says, Could not locate device support files. This iPhone 6 is running iOS 11.3.1 (15E302), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

Please help me if anyone have the device support for 11.3.1 (15E302)

Thanks

Comment: if you are getting 11.4.1 or below then follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741510/xcode-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image-12-0-16a5288q-or-11-4-1-deve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update to Xcode 9.3.

Another option is to download the 11.3 device support

[iOS 11.3](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport/issues/7)

Remove "(15E217)" from folder name, so it became "11.3". Restart Xcode.

Comment: Nothing is there to download

Comment: See the second answer there of ardalatmet

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade your xcode version to make the app capable to run in that version of iPhone , or you can get the support files form [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/nljz1fr7w22zlw1/11.3.zip)  and put in this path ( after unZip )

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 9.2 only supports up to iOS 11.2

Update Xcode